# Snowflake connector to python

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have python 3.11.0 version and I want to connect to snowflake as well.
I have installed the package, but my VS Code doesn't recognize it.
I saw in Snowflake Documentation that Snowflake Connector works with Python versions up to 3.9
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/python-install.html

Not sure if I can make it work or I need to re-install an older version of python.

Thank you

I tried pip install Snowflake, but it says I already have it installed.

Comment: If you use virtual environments you can run whichever version of Python you need in each environment

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the documentation, the Snowflake Python connector requires a Python version up to 3.9 - therefore yes, you would have to have installed one of the supported versions.
This ensures that the connector was tested and works with these versions of Python as well as ensures that your Python installation includes critical security fixes.